# Is doing a good deed conscious of the resulting karmic reaction, bad?

Tags: shiva, karma, astrology, yajur-veda, manuscripts

If one wants to do some good deeds like feeding stray dogs,and he/she is consciously well aware that they are accumulating good karma based on the karmic law, Does the deed count as good karma?

Comment: More or less the same as: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/20789/giving-alms-donation-charity-with-the-intention-of-getting-merit-will-give-me

Comment: If you are feeding hungry animals then its good (not bad) even if you are doing it with the motive of earning punya.

Comment: Being conscious of the good karma is not bad but expecting and craving for the good result is bad.