# Is Karma good or bad, dependent on intent or result?

Tags: karma

Sometimes, in this big city, when I travel, I often come across many unfortunate people, beggars, mutilated, helpless.

Sometimes, I want to help them and I do.

But, every time I am left wondering, **Is giving to beggars always a good karma?**

Think of it this way: Suppose a person is begging, you feel **daya** and you give something. But, actually that beggar is part of a cruel racket that mutilates innocent orphans to earn by begging.

So, you actually contributed towards evil with your donation. Isn't it? But,your intention was good and arose out of mercy.

What karmic fruit you will get? Because, you were not even aware of truth of that beggar.

Will you get rewarded for good intention or will you be punished for contributing to such a racket?
(This was a specific case.)

Generally speaking, 
if a person does something out of good intent but that karma ends up hurting someone. Is that a good karma? And will the actor of that karma get a reward or punishment?

Conversely, if a person out of malice does something bad, but ends up benefiting someone. Is that good or bad karma?

Comment: Read Gita Chapter 17 verses 20-22. It has the answer for you.

Comment: Related: [Donation at good place with certain mentioned intention accumulates good karma?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/8394/277)
 as mentioned by @SwamiVishwananda . Also see https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/5373/277

Comment: Is ur Q specifically about donation or generally about all sorts of Karmas?

Comment: I would like if i get answer to both. Donation is a specific case for the "all sorts" , no ?